# AdalServiceException: The application needs access to a service that your organization has not subscribed to

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

We're trying to authenticate one of our customers using an application we have and registered in Azure AD. However the customer gets this error upon executing the authentication request:

> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException:  AADSTS50000: There was an error issuing a token. AADSTS65005: The application needs access to a service that your organization `<name_of_company>` has not subscribed to. Please contact your Administrator to review the configuration of your service subscriptions.
>   Trace ID: e8746b39-33c6-4a4c-8608-906613fe73a9
>   Correlation ID: 14618bd8-b58e-4301-a269-510ff22cb600
>   Timestamp: 2016-12-20 13:07:46Z

Our method of authentication is basically this:

```
AuthenticationContext commonAuthContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common");
AuthenticationResult result = await commonAuthContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/",
                    _clientId, _replyUrl,
                    new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always));
```

Our AAD application is in microsoft.com directory and is called:

**cisnativeinstaller [wsfed enabled]**

Thanks
Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we develop an app which required the subscription service like Office 365 Exchange Online. This is error would occur when the users who doesn't have the subscription for it try to grant the consent to the app.

To fix this issue, the users need to be assign the corresponding licence before they can grant the consent for the app.

Or you may develop multi-tier applications, in this scenario, we need to add the client app to service app **knownClientApplications**. Refer links below about this scenario:

[How to sign in any Azure Active Directory (AD) user using the multi-tenant application pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview#understanding-user-and-admin-consent)( Consent and multi-tier applications section)

Comment: Fei thanks for the response. Yes this makes sense to me too. However, is there any facility in the ADAL library that could be used to allow proper consent to a sub-set of all possible services that our Installer App has been registered against in AAD?
Trying to avoid having to write a full client app. thanks

Comment: Hi @JeffSaremi Would you be able to help me with this question, please? I can't tell what I am doing wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69434600/the-app-needs-access-to-a-service-api-appid-that-your-organization-has-not  Thanks in advance.